# urdf tutorial in groovy

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to visualize the simplest model in the urdf tutorial "Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch" using the following command in Groovy:

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf
```

I get a blank(dark grey) display window named "urdf.vcg" instead of the usual Rviz window. However, running

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

Works as expected. Is it a problem with my installation or does the tutorial need to be updated?

JML

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63267/urdf-tutorial-in-groovy/) by [JML](https://answers.ros.org/users/4457/jml/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is similar to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/60888/urdf_tutorial-groovy-vs-fuerte/)

A [recent patch by Shaun Edwards](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robot_model_tutorials/blob/master/urdf_tutorial/urdf.rviz) adds a Groovy compatible config file.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Works, thanks (and thanks Shaun)!

JML

---

Originally posted by [JML](https://answers.ros.org/users/4457/jml/) with karma: 26 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just removed the line "" from the display.launch file and manually added RobotModel to rviz. Everytime I reload the display.launch file, I just uncheck and check the box to the right of RobotModel on rviz to reload the updated urdf model.

---

Originally posted by [sobotacm](https://answers.ros.org/users/4956/sobotacm/) with karma: 36 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2